# Start Activity GLSurfaceview.Renderer

Tags: android, augmented-reality, vuforia

I am Working with Vuforia QualComm SDK. In that working with image target. What i need to do is Detect Marker and have to navigate to another activity.

GL surfaceview is a View so how can i manipulate to load activity from GLSurfaceview. Should i Use to extend it from activity?

Need some help on this

Answer (score 0):

```
public class SkyActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
    private SkyGLSurfaceView mGLSurfaceView;
    private TextView mDateText;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        ...
        ...
        mGLSurfaceView = new SkyGLSurfaceView(this, mShowPlanets);
        ...
        ...
    }
}

...
...
...

public class SkyGLSurfaceView extends GLSurfaceView {
    private final OpenGLRenderer renderer; // Custom GL Renderer

    public SkyGLSurfaceView(Context context, boolean showPlanets) {
        super(context);
        renderer = new OpenGLRenderer(context); // Creating and attaching the renderer.
        setRenderer(renderer);
        ...
        ...
        ...
    }
...
...
...
}
```

something like that

Answer (score 0):

The view is in a `Context` (which is an Activity) and you can use this context to start a new `Activity` as usual.

```
//in GLSurfaceView : you can write this to launch a new Activity
((Activity)getContext()).startActivity(someIntent);
```